# inform android studio webview app that the HTML game is Over

Tags: android, html, cocos2d-js

I built multiple HTML games in cocos creator and uploaded them on server. I created an app using android studio which has list of those html games. By clicking on any of those games, app opens a webview and user can play that game.

when the game ends, the game should send the scores to the app so the app could save those scores. my problem is that I don't know how I can inform the app that the game is over and what the score is.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your Android application and HTML game website to a database. When the game is over, from your HTML Website just update a table in that database mentioning that the game is over and then your app should be continuously checking that database, as soon as your app will find that game is over, it will display a popup. Please go along these lines.

Comment: what if my game is offline?

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by offline, if you are able to access the game which is hosted on a server using your mobile webview, then it is not offline right?

Comment: user can download the game and run the game on local. also, it is not ideal that every app send request for server continuously

Answer (score 0):

There's a silly way we did communication between our app and the page inside the `WebView`. We used console logs. You can pass whatever you want into your app as long as it's a `String`. To create something like a tagging of the console logs, you make the console log look like TAG-something. First, you look for the TAG- part then remove that and use the remaining something part for the things you want to do with it. Of course, this is the last thing you want to do but I posted it for the sake of sharing my experience.

You can look up `JavascriptInterface` for website to app communication and `Webview.loadUrl("javascript:")` for app to website communication.